# Cannot send JSON data from Django to javascript

Tags: ajax, django

I need to send some data from `html` file to `django` for some processing and return it back using `ajax`
But the response goes to the error callback in the ajax call with status=0

This is the ajax code, I've tried both commented URLs

```
 function snapshot() {
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        console.log(imageData)
        //url:"{% url 'blind:getcaption' %}",

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blind/ajax/getcaption/',
          //url: /ajax/getcaption/ 
          data: {
            'img': imageData
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(request, status, error){
              console.log(request, " " ,status, " ", error)
          }

        });
      }
```

This is `views.py`

```
def getcaption(request):
    img = request.GET.get('img', None)
    data = {'caption': "This caption for test"}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And `urls.py`

```
app_name = 'blind'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^ajax/getcaption/$', views.getcaption, name='getcaption'),
]
```

But when I type in the url tap `url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blind/ajax/getcaption/` I get the json object back viewed in chrome

Comment: take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418411/how-to-send-an-array-field-for-django/54419523#54419523

Comment: also pass `xhr` as you first parameter in your error function and then `console.log(xhr.status); console.log(xhr.responseText)` to get details error message.

Comment: what about the url? How should I type it, to match your answer there!

Comment: just this: `url: '/blind/getcaption/'` and if you think my answer will be helpful for future readers then don't forget to upvote it :)

Comment: I got undefined when i used `console.log(xhr.responseText)`

Comment: did you passed `xhr` to error function as an argument ?

Comment: yes, error: function(xhr, status, error){ console.log(xhr.responseText);}

Comment: what does `xhr.status` show ?

Comment: status is 0, responseText is undefined

Comment: where is `ctx` defined ?

Comment: Did the link to my answer helped ?

Comment: No, the problem was i sent a get call but didn't edit the url to receive a parameter

Comment: You mean you forgot to add regex to your url pattern in urls.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can write the `url` in the ajax call as illustrated below and then parse the `JSON` you are getting on success.

```
    function snapshot() {
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        console.log(imageData)
        //url:"{% url 'blind:getcaption' %}",

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url : '{% url "getcaption" %}',
          data: {
            'img': imageData
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
          },
          error: function(request, status, error){
              console.log(request, " " ,status, " ", error)
          }

        });
      }
```

Then change your view, dump the dictionary to a json object before returning a json response:

```
def getcaption(request):
    img = request.GET.get('img', None)
    data = {'caption': "This caption for test"}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: You don't need to dump the data when using `JsonResponse` because that is done automatically. So I edited the answer.